# Remove child on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I'm getting the error **1120 access of undefined property** on

```
knop_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopVideos);
```

I want to have 9 buttons, playing a video. When a video is triggered, a button will be visible to exit the video, so another video can be played when you press another button.

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

knop_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel1);
knop_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel2);
knop_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel3);
knop_4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel4);
knop_5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel5);
knop_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel6);
knop_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel7);
knop_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel8);
knop_9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel9);

knop_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopVideos);
knop_stop.visible=false;

var videoArray:Array = new Array(
    "video/video01.flv",
    "video/video02.flv",
    "video/video03.flv",
    "video/video04.flv",
    "video/video05.flv",
    "video/video06.flv",
    "video/video07.flv",
    "video/video08.flv",
    "video/video09.flv"
 );

var filmAan = false;

function speel1(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {
        var myVideo1:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
        myVideo1.source = videoArray[0];
        addChild(myVideo1);
        myVideo1.x=340; 
        myVideo1.y=227;
        myVideo1.width=1360;
        myVideo1.height=908;
        filmAan = true;
        knop_stop.visible=true;
        function stopVideos(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
            removeChild(myVideo1);          
        }
    } else {
        knop_stop.visible = false;
    }

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where do you declare knop_stop?

Comment: Probably not where I think I did it..function stopVideos(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
            removeChild(myVideo1);          
        }

Comment: I am talking about the object on which you add the event listener.

Comment: knop_stop? are you sure it is not null?

Comment: Im sorry I have just started AS3 so im a total beginner, im not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the stopVideos function outside of the speel1 function if you want the event handler to see it.  When you place a function inside another one, you're limiting the scope of the internal function to the parent function. If you want the stopVidoes function to be visible to anything else try this:

```
function speel1(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {
        var myVideo1:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
        myVideo1.source = videoArray[0];
        addChild(myVideo1);
        myVideo1.x=340; 
        myVideo1.y=227;
        myVideo1.width=1360;
        myVideo1.height=908;
        filmAan = true;
        knop_stop.visible=true;
    } else {
        knop_stop.visible = false;
    }
}

function stopVideos(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
        removeChild(myVideo1);          
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback! But it seems the code is not working as I intended it to work. While the video is playing, the knop_stop button seems to be doing nothing. The knop_1 button seems to be removing the knop_stop button. How I want it to be is: While the video is playing, the knop_stop button should be turned invisible and remove the video playback. The knop_1 button should be doing nothing unless there is no video playing (FilmAan=false). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is knop_stop an object instance on the stage?  Does it get hidden by the first call?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `stopVideos` function outside the body of `speel1` function and define `myVideo1` outside of that function too:

```
var myVideo1:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
addChild(myVideo1);

function speel1(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {
        myVideo1.source = videoArray[0];
        myVideo1.x=340; 
        myVideo1.y=227;
        myVideo1.width=1360;
        myVideo1.height=908;
        filmAan = true;
        knop_stop.visible=true;

    } else {
        knop_stop.visible = false;
    }

}
function stopVideos(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
            removeChild(myVideo1);          
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback! But it seems the code is not working as I intended it to work. While the video is playing, the knop_stop button seems to be doing nothing. The knop_1 button seems to be removing the knop_stop button. How I want it to be is: While the video is playing, the knop_stop button should be turned invisible and remove the video playback. The knop_1 button should be doing nothing unless there is no video playing (FilmAan=false). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!